# What filetype do I need to make image in docs to work?

Tags: javascript, image, docxtemplater

I use ***docxtemplater*** to place my image in docx file but it keeps ending up an error image
[image: Like this]

I tried sending it as filelist, base64 , buffer but it never works

this is my code, thank you in advanced.

```
export const generateDocument = async (data, file, setFile) => {

  const opts = {
    centered: true,
    getImage: function (tagValue, tagName) {

      return PizZipUtils.getBinaryContent(data.imageData[0], (error, content) => content);
    },
    getSize: function (img, tagValue, tagName) {
      return [110, 130];
    },
  };

  loadFile(data.logo === "BBS" ? './BBS.docx' : "./PPT.docx", (error, content) => {
    if (error) {
      throw error;
    }
    let zip = new PizZip(content);
    let doc = new Docxtemplater(zip, {
      modules: [new ImageModule(opts)],
      paragraphLoop: true,
      linebreaks: true
    });
    doc.setData({...data});


    // render the document (replace all occurences of {first_name} by John, {last_name} by Doe, ...)
    doc.render();

    let out = doc.getZip().generate({
      type: "blob",
      mimeType: "docxType",
    });
    saveAs(out, 'Resume.docx');
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be other ways, but it definitely works if your `getImage()` function returns an `ArrayBuffer` with the image data. `Buffer` seems to be part of `node.js`. If your code runs in the browser, you can `npm install buffer`.

If your image data is base64 encoded, you could use this conversion function:

```
import { Buffer } from "buffer";

function base64DataURLToArrayBuffer(stringBase64) {
  const binaryString = window.atob(stringBase64);
  const len = binaryString.length;
  const bytes = Buffer.alloc(len, 0);
  for (let i = 0; i < len; i += 1) {
    const ascii = binaryString.charCodeAt(i);
    bytes[i] = ascii;
  }
  return bytes;
}
```